# Checking when python packages were last updated

Tags: python, package, conda, updates

Is there any way to check when were python packages last updated? I am getting some strange behaviour from one of the programs and I want to check if some undesired updates were performed.
I am using conda as a package manager.

Comment: See https://pypi.org/. And your additional package sources, if there are.

Comment: you can track your project dependencies or requirement file in version control (git) if there was any change.

Comment: Within conda or pip there is no command such "conda list" that would also display the dates when the packages were last updated on your machine? The only way is to manually check current package versions and search pypi.org for dates when the update happened?

Comment: The problem is that I haven't created the requirements file yet, so If I create it now I would just have the current status of the environment. But yes thanks for the note, will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I don't think you can get the date and time when packages were last updated. But you can try `pip list --outdated`. This will list the difference between the current installed packages version and the latest packages version available.